# Позиционирование в XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, разметка

Есть некоторый XML.

Требуется этот XML отобразить на WinForms приложение.

Я это вижу так:

XML считывается и какая-то базовая информация отображается в каком-нибудь датагриде. После того, как пользователь нажимает на строчку, то открывается форма редактирования этого XML элемента с атрибутами.

Проблемы вызывает у меня позиционирование...

Как понять, какой узел отображать на форме при нажатии на конкретную строчку?

Как понять в какой узел записывать изменения, после закрытия формы?

Если бы имелись уникальные атрибуты или все узлы были бы уникальными, то особых проблем это бы не составило...

Сам XML имеет какой-то такой вид:

```
<root>
    <config>
        <monitor/>
        <monitor/>
        <monitor/>
        <other/>
        <other/>
    </config>
<root/>
```

Или может быть в .Net что-то было придумано за меня, что решает эту задачку?

Comment: Каждый узел - это и есть уникальный объект. Кроме того, если вы используете XLinq, то там каждому объекту можно [назначить](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.addannotation(v=vs.110).aspx) свои [аннтотации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb292552(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Получается я могу создать что-то типа словаря ключ-значение и на основании этого выяснять положение и получать нужные узлы?

Comment: Можно и без словаря обойтись. Но если со словарем вам проще - да, так тоже можно.

Comment: Я имел ввиду:"Аннотация работаю подобно словарю или нет? Т.е я могу задать узлам аннотация, а потом по аннотация обратится к конкретному узлу?"

Comment: Нет, там связь только в одну сторону (из элемента можно достать аннотацию).

Comment: А можешь какой-нибудь пример набросать? Где было бы множество узлов с одинаковыми именами и при открытии определенного узла подгружалась информация с того узла на котором стоит курсор(Или допустим выбран в ComboBox'e)

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам, изучайте. Освойте, наконец, привязку данных.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Width = 500;

            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml("test.xml");

            var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = dataSet;

            var dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;

            var editButton = new Button { Parent = this, Top = 200, Left = 200, Text = "Edit", Enabled = false };
            editButton.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                var editForm = new EditForm(bindingSource);
                editForm.ShowDialog();
                bindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();
            };

            var tablesComboBox = new ComboBox { Parent = this, Top = 200 };
            tablesComboBox.DataSource = dataSet.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().Select(dt => dt.TableName).ToList();
            tablesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                string tableName = tablesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                bindingSource.DataMember = tableName;
                editButton.Enabled = dataSet.Tables[tableName].Columns.Count != 1;
            };
        }
    }

    public class EditForm : Form
    {
        public EditForm(BindingSource bindingSource)
        {
            var tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top, ColumnCount = 2, AutoSize = true };
            var okButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "OK", DialogResult = DialogResult.OK, Left = 200, Top = 220 };

            var dataSet = (DataSet)bindingSource.DataSource;

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataSet.Tables[bindingSource.DataMember].Columns)
            {
                if (!column.ColumnName.EndsWith("_Id"))
                {
                    var label = new Label { Parent = tableLayoutPanel, Text = column.ColumnName };
                    var textBox = new TextBox { Parent = tableLayoutPanel, Top = 200, Left = 150 };
                    textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, column.ColumnName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В качестве данных использует xml вида:

```
<root>
  <config>
    <monitor price="1000" width="1280" height="768" />
    <monitor price="1500" width="1440" height="800" />
    <monitor price="2000" width="1600" height="900" />
    <other price="20" feature="2" />
    <other price="30" feature="3" />
  </config>
</root>
```

Количество узлов и атрибутов произвольное, так же как и их имена.

Answer (score 1):

Форму редактирования открывать, передавая ей в конструктор узел, выбранный для редактирования - XmlNode. 
Форма что-то вроде этой:

```
class XmlNodeEditForm : Form
{
    XmlNode _nodeEdited;

    protected XmlNodeEditForm() { }
    protected XmlNodeEditForm(XmlNode nodeEdited) { _nodeEdited = nodeEdited; initEditNodeForm(); }

    void initEditNodeForm()
    {
        Text = _nodeEdited.Name;
        // кидаем на форму имена и значения атрибутов
        foreach (XmlAttribute a in _nodeEdited.Attributes)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = string.Format("{0}:", a.Name), Dock = DockStyle.Top });
            this.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Name = a.Name, Text = a.Name, Dock = DockStyle.Top });
        }
    }
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // сохраняем перед закрытием
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls) if (c is TextBox) _nodeEdited.Attributes[c.Name].Value = c.Text;
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

при выборе элемента пользователем нужно вызвать форму редактирования:

```
(new XmlNodeEditForm(selectedNode)).ShowDialog();
// здесь, после закрытия формы, нужно не забыть обновить отображение XML-узла для пользователя
```